# New Activity everyday by clicking a Button

Tags: java, android

I want to make that when user clicks the Start Button, the app shows ActivityFirst (on the first day when he downloaded app), the second day when s/he taps Start - ActivitySecond will be shown etc. When the app will not have any other Activity, I want to show a popup that will say that more Activities will be added in the future.

I can do popups, Activities, Buttons, onClicks etc.
But I can't do that everyday will there be a new Activity.

Can you help me, guys?

My idea:

- The user downloads the app,
- The user runs the app for the first time and clicks the Start Button (here comes the ActivityFirst)
- The user can look at this Activity for one day
- The user runs the app on the second day and taps the Start Button (here comes the ActivitySecond)

And so on.

I hope you understand my idea, it's a very annoying problem to me.

Comment: Why should you create new activity for each day just create only one activity and change its content on every day wise.

Comment: You can save a timestamp when users downloads your application.Then keep checking your current date  with your saved date,If you find its new day then show your second activity and so on.

Comment: You would have to release a new app for every new Activity... That's poor design

Comment: you can use shared preferences to save the often user enter the app.
Then you can use the value stored in your shared preference to replace the content of your activity

Comment: @MilapPancholi Maybe it's a better solution.. But how to make that activity will refresh everyday and show new content?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not necessarily. He could presumably release multiple days at a time.

Comment: @NancyY how make that timestamp?

Comment: @Simon you can call `setContentView` using different layouts. You can `findViewById` in an if statement. You can load whatever data you want based on the day all in one Activity

Comment: @cricket_007 why? When user downloads the app I want to application start a first activity when he will do a specific action. Second day when he run the app and do the same action (hit the button), there will be shown second activity and on the last activity i want to make a popup that more activities will be added in future.. I have a problem with the changing activity everyday only

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, that idea with new layout is very nice!

Comment: @simon String timeStamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "";

Comment: @Simon You should use dynamic content instead of static content that can be change based on your day is increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is save the timestamp of the first launch of the app.

Then, every time the user opens the activity, I would check how many days it's been since that timestamp, and populate the Activity accordingly.

All you need is one "DailyActivity", really.

Comment: How can I make the timestamp? I think it can really help me, thank you

Comment: @Simon use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get timestamp.

Comment: @SripadRaj and how i can make another layout every day with it? Is it should be in DailyAcitivity?

Comment: Well, what's gonna be the difference between the layouts?

Comment: @sofakingforever Buttons (buttons will show AlertDialogs) and text